# How can I show related links dynamically without performing a page postback?

Tags: ajax

I want to create Stack Overflow-like question asking functionality.

I have noticed as soon as the cursor is moved from Title textbox to Question, it is showing related links, without doing a page postback. I want to do something similar to that.

How can I perform this?

Comment: @ChrisF - Technically, AJAX is an acronym not a word. :-P

Comment: @Justin - all right in an acronym - AJAX (though it doesn't have the same ring to it)

Answer (score 1):

Use ajax.

When the title loses focus, use an ajax call to get related info and then show the results.

Comment: You may want to include some background on AJAX in case the OP doesn't already know what it means/how it works.

Comment: @Justin Niessner, I think the OP can use search tools to find out what AJAX is once he knows that's the route to go.

Answer (score 1):

Also, use jquery!
A useful library when dealing with AJAX.